# How to run Nuxt3 with docker (docker compose)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I want to run nuxt3 in a Docker container (using docker compose)

My Dockerfile looks like that:

```
FROM node:18.17.1-bullseye as build-stage

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build

FROM node:18.17.1-bullseye as production-stage
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/.output /app/.output



ENTRYPOINT ["node", ".output/server/index.mjs"]
```

When I start the container it quits with this error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
   throw err;
   ^
 
 Error: Cannot find module '/app/.output/server/index.mjs'
     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
   requireStack: []
 }
 
 Node.js v18.17.1
 exited with code 0
```

For me it looks like that the folder .output is not there. But I don't understand why and how to debug this.

EDIT:
#docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    environment:
      - HOST=0.0.0.0
```

#production.yaml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    volumes: []
```

You are right. When I remove the volumes from my docker-compose.yaml it works fine.
I start my application with this command:

```
docker compose -f docker-compose.yaml -f production.yaml up --build
```

Why is production.yaml not overwritten the docker-compose volume entry?

Comment: can you share your docker-compose.yaml file, this error maybe related to the volumes overwrites the node_modules folder

Comment: @yahyasghayron yes you are correct it can be caused by the overwrite but we need the docker-compose file to verify

Comment: I removed the volumes area and it is working. How can I override/deactivate volumes in my production file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing is related to the way volumes are managed in Docker Compose. When you use multiple Compose files with the -f flag, the order in which you specify them matters. The settings in the later Compose files will override those in the earlier ones. However, volumes defined in the docker-compose.yaml file are not overwritten by default when you use additional Compose files. Instead, volumes defined in multiple Compose files are merged.

In your case, you have volumes defined in both docker-compose.yaml and production.yaml. Since you're using -f docker-compose.yaml -f production.yaml, the volumes from both files are being merged. This is why you're seeing the issue where the volume from docker-compose.yaml is not being overridden by the empty volume definition in production.yaml.
By removing the volumes section from production.yaml, you ensure that the volume defined in docker-compose.yaml is used for development, and it won't be overridden

Comment: or try to rename the docker-compose.yaml to somting like `docker compose -f compose.yml -f production.yml up -d`